# Ошибка 401 Django rest_framework

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Делал все по туториалу , делаю простой бэкенд для андроид приложения не понимаю в чем проблема кажеться уже все перепробовал

[image: сайт с первой таблицей]

это код из views

'''

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from app_first.models import Adress
from app_first.serializers import AdressSerializers


class Adresses(APIView):


    def get(self, request):
        adds = Adress.objects.all()
        serializer = AdressSerializers(adds, many=True)
        return Response({"adds": serializer.data})
'''
```

сериализер:

```
from app_first.models import Adress


class AdressSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Сериализация adresa """
    adres = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    number_phon = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    x_re = serializers.FloatField(default=0)
    y_re = serializers.FloatField(default=0)
    start = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    stop = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        model = Adress
        fields = ("adress", "number_phon", "x_re", "y_re", "start", "stop")
```

модель:

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
import hashlib
from django.utils.text import slugify
from time import time


class Adress(models.Model):
    adres = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    number_phon = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    x_re = models.FloatField(default=0)
    y_re = models.FloatField(default=0)
    start = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    stop = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from app_first.views import *

from app_first.models import Adress
app_name = "adres"

urlpatterns = [
    path('room/', Adresses.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

просто зарегистрировать нужно в админ панели модель и задать там параметры

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app_first.models import Adress


class AdressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Комнаты чата"""
    list_display = ("adres", "number_phon")

    # def invited_user(self, obj):
    #     return "\n".join([user.username for user in obj.invited.all()])



admin.site.register(Adress, AdressAdmin)
```

[image: бэкенд]